# xsl how to direct the html content to xml content through clicking on the html uri link

Tags: xslt

I have a xml structure like below:

```
<PAGES>
<PAGE>
<PAGENUMBER>1</PAGENUMBER>
<SECTION>
<SECTIONITEM>
<ITEMNUMBER>1</ITEMNUMBER>
<TITLE>Interactive Forms</TITLE>
<TOPIC>
<SUBTITLE>Intro to Forms &amp; Attributes </SUBTITLE>
<ITEM>1</ITEM>
<PARA>This is the explanation for Topic ITEM 1</PARA>
<GRAPH>This the the link to the GRAPHIC</GRAPH>
</TOPIC>
</SECTIONITEM>
</SECTION>
</PAGE>
....<!-- lots of page blocks-->
</PAGES>
```

Now I have to generate a html summary that will list the PAGENUMBERs when certain conditions are satisfied and generate an `<a href>` link for the PAGENUMBER in the html. The request is that when user clicks on the page number link on the html, xml file will be popped up and directed to the related xml content.

Is this possible to link PAGENUMBER to the related xml content using xsl? I don't have enough experience to do this now.

Could anybody give me some suggestion or this could be done using other language like java or javascript?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is quite confusing. Your title seems completely unrelated to the body of the question. And the body of question is not clear either.

Comment: sorry i don't know where the title comes from and I corrected it.

Comment: There is no support for linking to a particular element in XML document rendered in a browser window, unless you transform the XML to HTML and then link an element in that HTML document.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your reply. This actually is a good idea but the purpose to link to a particular element in XML is because that there is the needs to compare and modify the XML content. So I guess this will not be accepted by others. need to discuss if this is acceptable. Thanks a lot.